# React Material UI Image Import Issue

Tags: reactjs, svg, import, material-ui, export

I am new to React JS. I am getting this error while I try to import and use an SVG Image.

`Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Here is my code.

```
import { ReactComponent as RightArrowIcon } from '../public/icons/RightArrow.svg';

function JobFetch() {
  return (
  <IconButton>
<RightArrowIcon />
</IconButton>
);
}
export default JobFetch;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you try to import the file from 'public' folder of the React app?
'Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.'

Comment: @AmrEraky I am trying to import the icon which I saved in public folder

Comment: You can't import any file from public folder in React app, it's not supported.
You have to move the icon file to 'src/' directory.

Comment: @AmrEraky Thank you so much for your valuable comment. It saved me